# Advice on how to use Qt Model View classes

Tags: c++, qt, architecture, model-view

So I have been writing a Sudoku game in C++.  I have most of the game logic done and tested, but I wanted to use Qt on top of it for the GUI.  I was trying to figure out the best way to work with the Qt classes for my needs.

As a test, I played around with QAbstractTableModel.  I subclassed it and had it access my existing data model and my existing controllers.  For now I am using QTableView to get basic rendering of the Sudoku board and basic "editing" (you can just change any value).  It looks nothing like what I want, but the functionality is all there (or can be added).

I wanted to make a data model and controllers to modify it all in C++, without depending on a framework.  Then I wanted to just have Qt sit on top.  So I have this working, and here is a quick "diagram" of how these things communicate at a high level

```
QTableView?
    ^
    |
    v
PuzzleModel : QAbstractTableModel
             ^              |
             |              |_____________
             |                            v
Real data model classes <------------ Controllers
```

My question is, how can I modify QTableView or should I create my own view or QWidget in order to display the data the way I want?

Ideally, I'd like to display a fixed size table (no headers, no resizing), and disallow multi-selecting.  There are some customizations on how I'd render various font styles/colors, but I think I can handle that pretty easily.  I'd also like to render each cell as either a number, or like this for "marks":

```
*-------------*         *-------------*
|  1   2   3  |         |   ******    |
|  4       6  |         |        *    |
|      8   9  |         |        *    |
*-------------*         *-------------*
```

So clearly I can't continue using QTableView out of the box.  Do I create my own QStyledItemDelegate and still use QTableView? Do I need to create a whole Widget? If I create

Just looking for some advice/direction from someone who knows the capabilities of the various Qt classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Continue to use `QTableView` and your `QAbstractTableModel`, and subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` to render *the cells* exactly how you want them. You can't change the inter-cell painting that way, though.

   Note, however, that you can achieve a lot of what you want (fonts, colors) by reacting to more [`Qt::ItemDataRole`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)s from your model's `data()` implementation.
2. Write a custom widget and *use a custom data provider interface*. Let me stress that: don't continue to use `QAbstractTableModel` when you implement your own `SudokuWidget`. It's much simpler for everyone that way (`QAbstractItemModel` is both way too abstract and way too specialised for the case of item views to be useful as a general data provider interface).

My advice is to go with (2). [Interview](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qt4-interview.html) is overrated.

Comment: Okay, number 2 sounds like a good option (it seemed like I would need to go that route).  Should I use something like `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` (or some other `QGraphics`* class) to derive from?  Or just the basic `QWidget`?  Or something else entirely.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel so I'd like to figure out the best starting point.  And it would be nice if I got some things like selection for free as I did with `QTableView`.

Comment: @Matt: I'm a traditionalist. If there's no strong advantage to using a [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph) (which is what `QGraphicsView` is), I don't. One thing to keep in mind is that if you create a custom widget with `QLineEdit`s as the entry fields, you'll get layouting and accessibility for free. Not so with `QGraphicsView`. That said, if you want to explore new things, you can try writing your UI in [QML](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtquick.html). It's enough of a toy example (no offense!) that the limitations of Qt-4.7's QML implementation aren't an issue.

Comment: Well, I had originally wanted to avoid doing too much "Qt-specific" stuff, but I did what seemed to be "easier" at the time.  I think I'll avoid the Graphics view.  However, I did come across this example: [link](http://code.google.com/p/sudoku-solver-qt/source/browse/trunk/src/SudokuDiagram.cpp) and I'm thinking I may just start with the `QTableView` and resize things and hide the headers as I need.  If I can get darker borders on the 9 main squares too that would be great.  Add a `QStyledItemDelegate` and I should be good.  Except that code uses `QTableWidget`, but I think `QTableView` works

Comment: I'm accepting your answer for option 1.  Since I can also just subclass the QTableView and get some of the other things I want. Thanks!